# SushiSwap contract RouteProcessor: Unknown command code

Tags: solidity, web3js, uniswap, web3.py, sushiswap

Im trying to swap tokens on sushiswap from python. For example im trying to swap 1 MATIC for 1 USDC. I have generated a route based on other answers on stackexchange but it didnt work to me and throws the following error *execution reverted: RouteProcessor: Unknown command code*.

Is there place where I can read more about contract inputs or how can I generate route to make it work?

```
contract_abi = '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_bentoBox","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"priviledgedUserList","type":"address[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"tokenIn","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"tokenOut","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Route","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"bentoBox","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract IBentoBoxMinimal","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenIn","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenOut","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"route","type":"bytes"}],"name":"processRoute","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"resume","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"priviledge","type":"bool"}],"name":"setPriviledge","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"transferValueTo","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountValueTransfer","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenIn","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenOut","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"route","type":"bytes"}],"name":"transferValueAndprocessRoute","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"uniswapV3SwapCallback","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]'

sushiswap_polygon_contract = '0x0a6e511Fe663827b9cA7e2D2542b20B37fC217A6'
matic_address = '0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE'
wrapped_matic_address = '0x0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270'
usdc_address = '0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174'

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://polygon-rpc.com'))

contract = web3.eth.contract(
    address=web3.to_checksum_address(sushiswap_polygon_contract),
    abi=contract_abi
)

account = web3.eth.account.from_key('')
address = account.address

value = web3.to_wei(1, 'ether')
encoded_matic_address = encode(['address'], [matic_address])
encoded_wrapped_matic_address = encode(['address'], [wrapped_matic_address])
encoded_usdc_address = encode(['address'], [usdc_address])

route = encoded_matic_address + encoded_wrapped_matic_address + encoded_usdc_address
swap_txn = contract.functions.processRoute(
    web3.to_checksum_address(matic_address),
    value,
    web3.to_checksum_address(usdc_address),
    0,
    web3.to_checksum_address(address),
    route
).build_transaction({
    'from': address,
    'value': value,
    'gasPrice': web3.eth.gas_price,
    'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(address),
})

>>> web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: RouteProcessor: Unknown command code
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

## Route Processor: route breakdown (with working example)

---

To build a route you'll want to know what you want to do, then look for those stages in the contract.
There are command bytes and pool bytes which are uint8, there is a share parameter which is uint16 and there are pool and token addresses.
You will need to either abi packed encode, or concatenate their unpadded hex values.

ex.

```py
from eth_abi.packed import encode_packed
route = encode_packed(['uint8', 'address', 'uint8', 'uint16', 'uint8', 'address', 'uint8', 'address'], [source, token_in, num, share, pool_type, pair, direction, to])
```

The path is a stream of unpadded bytes, at least the first of which will be command bytes.
[image]

- 1: If the token is at router, say for a multi hop or after unwrapping.
- 2: If from external account/contract
- 3: If with native coin

etc

Once it calls that command the next bytes are dependant on what you called (follow the function in the contract to see what is being decoded from the stream)

Let's break down the route from this transaction as an example:

- https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xff42abb0a2ffa6e36f72f2eb9cbdf3529ea9a4834415a754b6f857ecc6aa157c

Route code:

```
0x0301ffff0201cd353f79d9fade311fc3119b841e1f456b54e8580d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270040d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf127000cd353f79d9fade311fc3119b841e1f456b54e85801685e1e383e758b49b3f3413b5c5281c225b2ce1a
```

Broken up:

> 03 ->
> 01 ->
> ffff ->
> 02 ->
> 01 ->
> cd353f79d9fade311fc3119b841e1f456b54e858 ->
> 0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270 ->
> 04 ->
> 0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270 ->
> 00 ->
> cd353f79d9fade311fc3119b841e1f456b54e858 ->
> 01 ->
> 685e1e383e758b49b3f3413b5c5281c225b2ce1a

---

Here are each of those actions and values consumed from stream along with them.

#### command 03

(commandCode == 3) processNative(stream);

```
  /// @notice Processes native coin: call swap for all pools that swap from native coin
  /// @param stream Streamed process program
  function processNative(uint256 stream) private {
    uint256 amountTotal = address(this).balance;
    distributeAndSwap(stream, address(this), NATIVE_ADDRESS, amountTotal);
  }
```

- num of pools to pull from:
- - 01
- shares to swap on pool:
- - ffff

```
  /// @notice Distributes amountTotal to several pools according to their shares and calls swap for each pool
  /// @param stream Streamed process program
  /// @param from Where to take liquidity for swap
  /// @param tokenIn Input token
  /// @param amountTotal Total amount of tokenIn for swaps 
  function distributeAndSwap(uint256 stream, address from, address tokenIn, uint256 amountTotal) private {
    uint8 num = stream.readUint8();
    unchecked {
      for (uint256 i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        uint16 share = stream.readUint16();
        uint256 amount = (amountTotal * share) / 65535;
        amountTotal -= amount;
        swap(stream, from, tokenIn, amount);
      }
    }
  }
```

#### pool type: 02

(poolType == 2) wrapNative(stream, from, tokenIn, amountIn);

```
  /// @notice Makes swap
  /// @param stream Streamed process program
  /// @param from Where to take liquidity for swap
  /// @param tokenIn Input token
  /// @param amountIn Amount of tokenIn to take for swap
  function swap(uint256 stream, address from, address tokenIn, uint256 amountIn) private {
    uint8 poolType = stream.readUint8();
    if (poolType == 0) swapUniV2(stream, from, tokenIn, amountIn);
    else if (poolType == 1) swapUniV3(stream, from, tokenIn, amountIn);
    else if (poolType == 2) wrapNative(stream, from, tokenIn, amountIn);
    else if (poolType == 3) bentoBridge(stream, from, tokenIn, amountIn);
    else if (poolType == 4) swapTrident(stream, from, tokenIn, amountIn);
    else revert('RouteProcessor: Unknown pool type');
  }
```

- direction and fake:
- - 01
- to (pair):
- - cd353f79d9fade311fc3119b841e1f456b54e858
- wrap token (matic):
- - 0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270

```
  /// @notice Wraps/unwraps native token
  /// @param stream [direction & fake, recipient, wrapToken?]
  /// @param from Where to take liquidity for swap
  /// @param tokenIn Input token
  /// @param amountIn Amount of tokenIn to take for swap
  function wrapNative(uint256 stream, address from, address tokenIn, uint256 amountIn) private {
    uint8 directionAndFake = stream.readUint8();
    address to = stream.readAddress();

    if (directionAndFake & 1 == 1) {  // wrap native
      address wrapToken = stream.readAddress();
      if (directionAndFake & 2 == 0) IWETH(wrapToken).deposit{value: amountIn}();
      if (to != address(this)) IERC20(wrapToken).safeTransfer(to, amountIn);
    } else { // unwrap native
      if (directionAndFake & 2 == 0) {
        if (from != address(this)) IERC20(tokenIn).safeTransferFrom(from, address(this), amountIn);
        IWETH(tokenIn).withdraw(amountIn);
      }
      payable(to).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
  }
```

#### command 04

(commandCode == 4) processOnePool(stream);

- token (matic):
- - 0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270

```
  /// @notice Processes ERC20 token for cases when the token has only one output pool
  /// @notice In this case liquidity is already at pool balance. This is an optimization
  /// @notice Call swap for all pools that swap from this token
  /// @param stream Streamed process program
  function processOnePool(uint256 stream) private {
    address token = stream.readAddress();
    swap(stream, address(this), token, 0);
  }
```

#### pool type 0

(poolType == 0) swapUniV2(stream, from, tokenIn, amountIn);

- pool:
- - cd353f79d9fade311fc3119b841e1f456b54e858
- direction:
- - 01
- to (destination wallet):
- - 685e1e383e758b49b3f3413b5c5281c225b2ce1a

```
  /// @notice UniswapV2 pool swap
  /// @param stream [pool, direction, recipient]
  /// @param from Where to take liquidity for swap
  /// @param tokenIn Input token
  /// @param amountIn Amount of tokenIn to take for swap
  function swapUniV2(uint256 stream, address from, address tokenIn, uint256 amountIn) private {
    address pool = stream.readAddress();
    uint8 direction = stream.readUint8();
    address to = stream.readAddress();

    (uint256 r0, uint256 r1, ) = IUniswapV2Pair(pool).getReserves();
    require(r0 > 0 && r1 > 0, 'Wrong pool reserves');
    (uint256 reserveIn, uint256 reserveOut) = direction == 1 ? (r0, r1) : (r1, r0);

    if (amountIn != 0) {
      if (from == address(this)) IERC20(tokenIn).safeTransfer(pool, amountIn);
      else IERC20(tokenIn).safeTransferFrom(from, pool, amountIn);
    } else amountIn = IERC20(tokenIn).balanceOf(pool) - reserveIn;  // tokens already were transferred

    uint256 amountInWithFee = amountIn * 997;
    uint256 amountOut = (amountInWithFee * reserveOut) / (reserveIn * 1000 + amountInWithFee);
    (uint256 amount0Out, uint256 amount1Out) = direction == 1 ? (uint256(0), amountOut) : (amountOut, uint256(0));
    IUniswapV2Pair(pool).swap(amount0Out, amount1Out, to, new bytes(0));
```

---

### A working example:

This Following script swaps .5 matic to usdc on Polygon mainnet.

| WARNING |
| --- |
| Please note that 0 is used for amountOutMin here, but you should always use the amount out you want minus a percent slippage you are willing to take, if front running is a concern. |

```py
# imports and initialisations (replace with your own set up)
from net import con; w3 = con('POLYGON') # i.e from web3 import Web3; w3 = Web3(Provider(Endpoint))
# account
from os import getenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
KEY = getenv('TKEY')
EOA = getenv('TRON')
#----------------------


#---
USDC_ADDRESS = '0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174'
WMATIC_ADDRESS = '0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270'
WMATIC_USDC_ADDRESS = '0xcd353F79d9FADe311fC3119B841e1f456b54e858'

ROUTER_ADDRESS = '0x0a6e511Fe663827b9cA7e2D2542b20B37fC217A6'

ROUTER_ABI = '''[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_bentoBox","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"priviledgedUserList","type":"address[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"tokenIn","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"tokenOut","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Route","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"bentoBox","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract IBentoBoxMinimal","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenIn","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenOut","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"route","type":"bytes"}],"name":"processRoute","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"resume","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"priviledge","type":"bool"}],"name":"setPriviledge","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"transferValueTo","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountValueTransfer","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenIn","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenOut","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"route","type":"bytes"}],"name":"transferValueAndprocessRoute","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"uniswapV3SwapCallback","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]'''
ERC20_ABI = ''' [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"},{"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"deposit","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Withdrawal","type":"event"}] '''

router = w3.eth.contract(address=ROUTER_ADDRESS, abi=ROUTER_ABI)
wmatic = w3.eth.contract(address=WMATIC_ADDRESS, abi=ERC20_ABI)


# ----

# A minimum viable path is:
# - source (command bytes): most likely your wallet or the router.
# - token_in: token to swap from 
# - num: number of pool routes to calls swap on
# - share: amount of totalAmount per swap
# - pool_type: v2 or v3, or to weth etc, check the list above or the function in the contract
# - pair: pool to swap on
# - direction token0 to token1 or vice versa 
# - to: destination ie router if another hop, or unwrap, and your address if done

# We want to use pre wrapped matic from wallet and swap for usdc, so let's look for those stages:

# The token is coming from our wallet so we select 2 'processUserERC20'
# if (commandCode == 2) processUserERC20(stream, amountIn);
source = 0x02

# Following this through the contract, we can see it pulls an address from the stream
# and as this our token, in lets assign it the wmatic address
# function processUserERC20(uint256 stream, uint256 amountTotal) private {
#   address token = stream.readAddress();
token_in = WMATIC_ADDRESS

# It then wants the number of 'routes' to call swap on, and how the total amount swapped will be split across them
# For simplicity (and as I have not played around with this much) we will set 1 pool route, full amount from pool
# uint8 num = stream.readUint8();
# ..uint16 share = stream.readUint16();
num = 0x01 # 1 pool route
share = 0xffff # full amount from pool route

# Now we prepare the pool bytes, followed by values the called command will consume from the stream
# v2 has the liquidty for this swap so we put 0
#   if (poolType == 0) swapUniV2(stream, from, tokenIn, amountIn);
pool_type = 0x00

# This function takes the address of pool, 0 or 1 for direction, and an address for destination
# We know the pool, direction we can get from pool, and as this is a single hop the destination will be the externally owned accounts address
# function swapUniV2(uint256 stream, address from, address tokenIn, uint256 amountIn) private {
#   address pool = stream.readAddress();
#   uint8 direction = stream.readUint8();
#   address to = stream.readAddress();
pair = WMATIC_USDC_ADDRESS
direction = 0x01 # token 1 to 0 or 0 to 1 (check pool or call it and sort them)
to = EOA

# Encode them
from eth_abi.packed import encode_packed
route = encode_packed(['uint8', 'address', 'uint8', 'uint16', 'uint8', 'address', 'uint8', 'address'], [source, token_in, num, share, pool_type, pair, direction, to])

PROCESSED_ROUTE = f'0x{route.hex()}'
print(PROCESSED_ROUTE)


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# driver
tx = {
        'from': EOA,
        'value':0,
        'chainId': 137,
        'gas': 250000,
        'maxFeePerGas': w3.eth.gas_price * 2,
        'maxPriorityFeePerGas': w3.to_wei('40', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(EOA)
}

def sign_tx(tx, key):
  sig = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction
  signed_tx = sig(tx, private_key=key)
  return signed_tx

def send_tx(signed_tx):
  w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
  tx_hash = w3.to_hex(w3.keccak(signed_tx.rawTransaction))
  return tx_hash

def main():
  approve = wmatic.functions.approve(ROUTER_ADDRESS, 500000000000000000).build_transaction(tx)
  print ('[-] Approving... ')
  tx_hash = send_tx(sign_tx(approve, KEY))
  receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
  print (f'[+] Approved: {tx_hash}\n[>] {receipt}')

  tx.update({'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(EOA)})
  swap = router.functions.processRoute(
    WMATIC_ADDRESS,
    500000000000000000,
    USDC_ADDRESS,
    0,
    EOA,
    PROCESSED_ROUTE
  ).build_transaction(tx)
  print('[-] Simulating swap...')
  w3.eth.call(swap)
  print('[-] Attempting swap...')
  tx_hash = send_tx(sign_tx(swap, KEY))
  receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
  print (f'[>] Hash of swap: {tx_hash}\n[>] {receipt}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```